# How can I get started with Coinbase Advanced Trade REST API

Tags: cryptography, coinbase-api

I'm trying to create a bot that trades using "Coinbase Advanced Trade" specifically with Python.

For the past couple of weeks I've been trying to formulate some code to get me connected to Advanced Trade and ready to start making methods to buy and sell based on my strategies. They talk about how their platform uses REST API; however, provide no source code or examples on how to get started.

I'm basically just asking for some source code to get connected to Advanced Trade, and its technical indicators (The documentation says the API uses Trading View for their indicators) so I can go about my day and start implementing my strategies into my bot to get it working.

Heres some documentation from coinbase regarding to my question:

https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/advanced-trade-api/docs/rest-api-overview

I tried using chatGPT to help me, but the AI is so outdated.

I scrolled through some of the FAQs and Forums, couldn't find anything